# Get Military Time Zone Abbreviation

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime, abbreviation

I have a `org.joda.time.DateTime` object and I need to retrieve the military time zone abbreviation (e.g. **T** for UTC-07:00, **U** for UTC-08:00, **Z** for UTC±00:00).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones

Here's how I'm currently doing it:

```
int offset = dt.getZone().toTimeZone().getRawOffset() / (60 * 60 * 1000);
String timeZoneCode = timeZoneCodeMap.get(offset);
```

where `timeZoneCodeMap` is a `HashMap<Integer, String>` that is initialized with entries like the following

```
timeZoneCodeMap.put(1, "A");
timeZoneCodeMap.put(2, "B");
timeZoneCodeMap.put(3, "C");
...
timeZoneCodeMap.put(-10, "W");
timeZoneCodeMap.put(-11, "X");
timeZoneCodeMap.put(-12, "Y");      
timeZoneCodeMap.put(0, "Z");
```

Does there exist a function or library (in Joda or otherwise) that already contains a mapping of time zones to military abbreviations?

Feel free to let me know if there is a better way to calculate the offset as well.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/joda-time/discussion/337835/thread/51d091f2/

Comment: I've not tried this with JODA but I know that to get this to work with java.util.Date (which sucks, I know) I had to do a bit of manual finagling.

Comment: As assylias points out, no such support in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) is the successor to Joda-Time, and is integrated with the upcoming Java 8. If you care about this feature, you might check with the JSR team to see about adding support. It may be only a matter of adding a formatter implementation (I don't know, I haven't thought it through). The team has been open to contributors in the past, and may still accept your input or code donation.

Comment: What's so bad about writing your own method?

Comment: Because a better one might already exist.

Comment: Be aware that not all time zones use a whole number of hours. Quite a few time zones use half and quarter hours, and until 1955 Bombay time was UTC+4:51.

Comment: Today I was instructed to just use Zulu time, so I no longer need this code. If someone still cares enough to try to get a solution into JSR 310, I'm sure someone out there would appreciate it someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is such little code, that you might as well just do it yourself ...

```
static final String MAPPING = "YXWVUTSRQPONZABCDEFGHIKLM";
...
  String timeZoneCode = MAPPING.substring(offset + 12, offset + 13);
```

Comment: Accepting this as more clever alternative to using a HashMap, assuming that the offset has already been normalized to account for half and quarter hours as @Ben mentioned in his comment on my question.