# Convert yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z' to normal "HH:mm a" format

Tags: java, android, datetime, timestamp, simpledateformat

I have a problem in displaying the date in my Application.

I am getting timestamp as:

> 2017-08-02T06:05:30.000Z

But as per this the **actual time** is:

> 2017:08:02 11:35 AM

But after converting using my code it displays the time as:

> 6:00 am

How to show it as current time?

My code is given below:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat timestampformat = 
                   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'");

private static SimpleDateFormat sdftimeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

private static SimpleDateFormat getSdftimeformat() {
    return sdftimeformat;
}
public static String timeStampConvertToTime(String time) {
    Date date1 = null;

    try {
        date1 = timestampformat.parse(time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String formattedTime = getSdftimeformat().format(date1);
    return formattedTime;
}
```

Comment: where is this method:  **getSdftimeformat()** ?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃ПepeúpaツPlease check the edited answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing is that you're using `mm:ss.mmm` in your format. According to [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `m` represents the minutes, so you must change it to `mm:ss.SSS` because `S` represents the milliseconds.

Another detail is that the `Z` in the end is the [timezone designator for UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) and it can't be ignored (at least it shouldn't). You must use the corresponding pattern for that, which is `X`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
Date date = sdf.parse("2017-08-02T06:05:30.000Z");
```

**PS:** the `X` pattern was introduced in Java 7. If you're using Java <= 6, the only alternative is to treat `Z` as a literal (an ugly workaround, I admit) and set the UTC as the timezone used by the parser:

```
// treat "Z" as literal
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
// use UTC as timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = sdf.parse("2017-08-02T06:05:30.000Z");
```

With this, the date will have the value corresponding to 06:05 in UTC. To format the time to your timezone, you must use another `SimpleDateFormat` with the corresponding timezone:

```
// output format: hour:minute AM/PM
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
// assuming a timezone in India
outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

The output will be:

> 11:35 AM

If you don't set a timezone, it'll use the system's default. But the default can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to explicity set a specific timezone as above.

I also used `java.util.Locale` to set the language to English, because some locales can have different symbols for AM/PM. If you don't specify one, it'll use the system default and it's not guaranteed to be one in which the symbols are the ones you need (some locales uses "a.m./p.m." or another different formats, so it's better to use an explicit locale).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To parse the input you can use the `ZonedDateTime` class, which has full support to timezones and it makes the conversion to another zones very easy. Then you use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the output:

```
// parse the input
ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-08-02T06:05:30.000Z");
// convert to another timezone
ZonedDateTime z = parsed.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
// format output
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(fmt.format(z));
```

The output will be:

> 11:35 AM

If the input **always** has `Z` in the end, you can also use the `Instant` class:

```
// parse the input
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-08-02T06:05:30.000Z");
// convert to a timezone
ZonedDateTime z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
```

Note that I used `hh` for the hours: this will format using values from 1 to 12 (it makes sense because I'm also using the AM/PM designators). If you want values from 0 to 23, use `HH` instead - check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) for more details.

Also note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `IST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use the system's default timezone with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but this can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to explicity use a specific one.

Comment: Nice answer - well explained

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SimpleDateFormat class and specify the format you want to parse from , like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

long timeStamp = sdf.parse('your_timestamp').getTime();

SimpleDateFormat currentDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());

String time =currentDateFormat.format(timeStamp); // Formatted time in string form
```

Answer (score -1):

try this your will get result

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

                // set your format in df variable

                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "HH:mm a");
                try {
                    cal.setTime('your value');

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
String localtime = df.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: causing java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-08-02T06:05:30.000Z"

Answer (score -1):

use this for get current time.

```
  Calendar cal = 
  Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
  Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
  DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a"); 
 // you can get seconds by adding  "...:ss" to it
 date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30")); 

 String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
```

change time zone to your time zone

Comment: @Rose is this answer is working for you then please accept

Comment: Please check i am given like this but didn't work                        
     //--------------------------------------------------                                                                                           
   DateFormat timezone= timezone=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
String time="2017-08-02T06:05:30.000Z";
 Date date1 = null;
        try { date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.mmm'Z'").parse(time);
            timezone.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        } catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
        return  timezone.format(date1);

Answer (score -1):

I assume the Z in Rose's timestamp is zulu time, it isn't really correct to hard code the conversion from zulu time to his local time zone (GMT+5:30 we are assuming).  It might be OK if it is always returning Z but if it is 
[military time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) you would need something that can handle all the possible timezones.

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965056/get-military-time-zone-abbreviation) implies there is no built in way to do it.  Need to understand where the timestamp is coming from to really answer the question.